# Multiple arrays query in wordpress query_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created multiplу array query like this:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => product
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => kind_of
                            [value] => text_of_kind
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => production_type
                            [value] => 'Production sample name'
                            [type] => char
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

... but in loop I get both results (like [relation] => OR) What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta queries shouldn't be nested in an array.

```
$query_args = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array( 'key' => 'foo' ),
    array( 'key' => 'bar' )
);
```

Check [WP_Meta_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) in the Codex.